# ¿Cómo insertar datos a la clase herencia cuando genero un objeto en la clase padre en Hibernate?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

Hola tengo una clase Account y una subclase Shop que hereda de Account. Quiero que cuando creo un objeto de la clase Account se me genere un objeto Shop que apunte al objeto Account creado.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Account implements Serializable {}

@Entity
@Table(name = "shop")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name="id")
public class Shop extends Account {}

Account account = new Account(1, "Manolito");
Account result = AccountRepository.save(account);

//Como hago para generar el objeto shop que apunte al objeto creado account
```

Answer (score 1):

Para que un objeto de la clase Shop apunte a un objeto de la clase `Account`, deberías establecer una relación entre ellas, por ejemplo:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "account")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.JOINED)
public class Account implements Serializable {
    private Shop shop;
}
```

Y crear la relación:

```
Account account = new Account(1, "Manolito");
Shop shop = new Shop();
account.setShop(shop);
```